# How to install Docker from the Source code?

Tags: build, makefile, installation, docker

I am trying to install docker from the source code downloaded from github.com/docker/docker

I am unable to install it from the source code .
The Makefile present creates a image , but i want to install it in my system. 
Can anyone suggest solution ?

I am using UBUNTU 14.04

Comment: This question has been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53407108/how-to-build-docker-ce-from-source-on-macos

Answer (score 0):

Well, idk if this works for your linux distro. (looks like it is ubuntu) but i run kali linux and even if we have different commands to use the process is just as same in every linux distro.

first, before we jump on, we need to update our linux repos.(repositories)

```
sudo apt update
```

and,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then,

```
sudo apt install git
```

[This installs git]

Now we can start cloning git repos. into our system

go to your desired folder/working directory and type:

```
sudo git clone "link of the git repo. without the commas"
```

i would better suggest you to just:

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

[To install docker by apt]

Answer (score -1):

it's better to install it via the docker package and update it to the last version. This is the best way to install docker.

Comment: Its true , but i want to add few modidficataion and install and test in my system. 
can u suggest how i can install from the source code?

Comment: That doesn't even come close to answering the question.