# How to build docker-ce from source on macOS

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Anyone knows if there's a guide to build from source and replace docker binary on Mac with it?

The readme doesn't say so I try some make target but got https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3353

***Edited***
What I was trying to do, to be exact, is to debug docker cli to see why the Auth doesn't work for a single developer in my former company, regardless all factor checked and verified to be correct.

Comment: Hm, does docker for mac use the same binary as the linux version? I thought it's a custom one.

Comment: I saw in Make file:

.PHONY: binary-osx
binary-osx: ## build executable for macOS
 ./scripts/build/osx

Comment: Ah, right, make targets. I need more coffee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, checkout the repo of docker cli (it was confusing at first which part of docker live where). But the cli is at:
`git@github.com:docker/cli.git`

Build it( this build dist for all platform), assuming you have `make` already:
`make -f docker.Makefile binary cross`

Then either use this binary(this is for Mac), for example:
`build/docker-darwin-amd64 pull mysql`

Or backup and replace your original `/usr/local/bin/docker` with the binary above.

Answer (score 0):

Since on macOS you're not going to run the engine, you may try a different approach. Building the `docker` client using the Makefile requires docker engine, and a docker client, which you may not have.

I'm building `docker` (the client) from the docker/cli repository as a plain Go project:

- Clone the repo:

  ```
  $ git clone https://github.com/docker/cli.git
  ```
- Build `master`, or checkout a specific tag:

  ```
  $ git checkout v19.03.6
  ```
- `cd` into the repo, create a build directory, and create the require Go project structure:

  ```
  $ cd cli
  $ mkdir -p build/src/github.com/
  $ cd build/src/github.com/
  $ ln -s ../../.. cli
  ```
- `cd` into the `build` directory and set the `GOPATH`:

  ```
  $ cd ../..
  $ export GOPATH=$(pwd)
  ```
- Build the `docker` client:

  ```
  $ go build github.com/docker/cli/cmd/docker
  ```
- Copy the binary from the `build` directory, e.g.:

  ```
  $ cp docker /usr/local/bin
  ```

You'll notice that some build-related information is not set:

```
./docker version
Client:
 Version:           unknown-version
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.8
 Git commit:        unknown-commit
 Built:             unknown-buildtime
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

You can pass a suitable `-ldflags` argument to set those variables as in:

```
$ go build \
    -ldflags \
    "-X github.com/docker/cli/cli/version.GitCommit=${docker_gitcommit} \
     -X github.com/docker/cli/cli/version.Version=${version} \
     -X \"github.com/docker/cli/cli/version.BuildTime=${build_time}\""
```

provided you have set the `docker_gitcommit`, `version` and `build_time` variables.  The escaped quotes in the third flag are required if `build_time` contain spaces (as the upstream `docker` binaries do).

Hope this helps.