# Is it possible to debug docker client

Tags: docker, go

I wonder if it is possible to debug command like `docker pull` against its source (https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/cli/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/client/image_create.go I guess) ?

Comment: I'd try to build it locally and then add some logging in the relevant functions. You can also try using something like https://github.com/derekparker/delve which has an integration with VSCode (if you prefer a visual debugger), but I haven't used it and not sure how well it works.

Comment: Look like you might know https://stackoverflow.com/q/53407108/754250

Comment: I agree with @MihaiTodor that first source code should be downloaded and then built, find the debugger based on the source code language. For instance, C has debugger gdb, Java has debugger jdb etc. This question is more about methodalogy

Comment: Are you able to read my comment above?